# Setting up dirPagination module

Tags: angularjs, pagination

Trying to set up this [great looking pagination module](http://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/108/paginate-almost-anything-in-angularjs) to use for my small search app using Elasticsearch and AngularJS.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to load the first 100 results on the initial search request, displaying 10 results on the page at a time.

What I have on my ng-repeat(replaced with dir-paginate for this module) is

```
<li dir-paginate="page in results.documents | itemsPerPage:pageSize" current-page="currentPage" total-items="totalItems">
```

With pageSize and totalItems both set in the controller and ES request. PageSize is set to 10 and totalItems is set to 100.

In the pagination control I have `<dir-pagination-controls max-size="10" direction-links="true" boundary-links="true"></dir-pagination-controls>`. However when I click on a number in the control, nothing happens, why?

I have the first 100 results loaded into the UI from the initial search request, so it should just filter through them, 10 at a time, right? The module says it is suppose to be plug and play so I'm assuming as long as you have the settings right, it already has a built in filter to do that.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `total-items` attribute from your `<li>`.

Total-items are only needed for `async` calls. Since, you are loading your data (100 records) right upfront. So, you don't need to set this property.

Here is what the documentation says:

> **total-items** - When working with asynchronous data (i.e. data that is
>   paginated on the server and sent one page at a time to the client),
>   you would be sent only one page of results and then some meta-data
>   containing the total number of results. In this case, the pagination
>   directive would think that your one page of result was the full
>   dataset, and therefore no pagination is needed. To prevent the default
>   behaviour, you need to specify the total-items attribute, which will
>   then be used to calculate the pagination. For more information see the
>   section on working with asynchronous data below.